# how to build a recursive PostgreSQL function to return a JsonB Array? PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm fighting with this for hours.

I simple can't figure it out.

I need to return a JsonB Array, representing the hierarchical structure of menus and submenus of my application.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."FncGetMenus" (
  "eCodMenuPai" integer = 0
)
RETURNS jsonb [] AS
$body$
DECLARE
  vQuery RECORD;
  vJsonRecord Jsonb;
  vJsonMenu Jsonb;
  vJsonObjectSubMenus Jsonb;
  vJsonArraySubMenus Jsonb[];
  vJsonArrayReturn Jsonb[];
BEGIN
   
  --Get each menu into a vQuery RECORD
  FOR vQuery IN 
    SELECT
      m.*
    FROM
      "TabMenuSistema" m
    WHERE 
      COALESCE(m."CodMenuPai", 0) = "eCodMenuPai"
    ORDER BY
      COALESCE(m."CodMenuPai", 0),
      m."CodMenu"  
  LOOP
    --Build a JsonObject for each menu
    vJsonRecord = row_to_json(vQuery                          
    );    
    
    --Get the submenus of this menu
    SELECT 
      f.*
    FROM
      "FncGetMenus"(vQuery."CodMenu") f 
    INTO
      vJsonArraySubMenus;
     
    --Create an Object containing the submenus 
    SELECT 
      json_build_object('SubMenus', vJsonArraySubMenus)  
    INTO
      vJsonObjectSubMenus;
      
    raise notice 'json record: %', vJsonRecord;
    raise notice 'json object submenu: %', vJsonObjectSubMenus;
      
    --Include the SubMenus object to a new JsonObject
    vJsonMenu = vJsonRecord || vJsonObjectSubMenus;
    
    raise notice 'json vJsonMenu: %', vJsonMenu;
     
    --Append the new JsonMenu with it´s children to the result array
    vJsonArrayReturn =  vJsonArrayReturn || vJsonMenu; 
    
    raise notice 'result: %', vJsonArrayReturn;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN vJsonArrayReturn;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100;
```

**First problem:**

The output is an Object and not an Array:

**Second problem:**

All the result inner elements that should be Objects, seem to have been appended as string

**Third Problem**

The content is escaped, but I suppose that it has to do with the second problem.

**fourth problem:**

Couldn´t find a way to return an empty Jsonb Array, insted of null.

Probably there is a less verbose and faster way to achieve this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

I tried to supply the Raise Notice text and the output of the function, but it was not possible due to code format restrictions.

So, here goes the DDL and DML scripts to the table in question.

```
CREATE TABLE public."TabMenuSistema" (
  "CodMenu" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "DesMenu" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  "CodMenuPai" INTEGER,
  "IndPermiteRelatorio" BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(1, 'Configurações');       
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(2, 'Cadastros');
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(3, 'Entradas');
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(4, 'Saídas');       
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(6, 'Administrativo');       
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(7, 'Financeiro');       
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(8, 'Gerencial');       
INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu") VALUES(9, 'Relatórios');

INSERT INTO "TabMenuSistema" ("CodMenu", "DesMenu", "CodMenuPai") VALUES(10, 'Locais', 2);
```

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Got IT!!

I mistook PostgreSQL Array of Json with Json Array.

Here is the correct script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."FncGetMenus" (
  "eCodMenuPai" integer = 0
)
RETURNS jsonb AS
$body$
DECLARE
  vQuery RECORD;
  vJsonRecord Jsonb;
  vJsonMenu Jsonb;
  vJsonObjectSubMenus Jsonb;
  vJsonArraySubMenus Jsonb;
  vJsonArrayReturn Jsonb;
BEGIN
  vJsonArrayReturn = '[]'::Jsonb;
  
  --Get each menu into a vQuery RECORD
  FOR vQuery IN 
    SELECT
      m.*
    FROM
      "TabMenuSistema" m
    WHERE 
      COALESCE(m."CodMenuPai", 0) = "eCodMenuPai"
    ORDER BY
      COALESCE(m."CodMenuPai", 0),
      m."CodMenu"  
  LOOP
    --Build a JsonObject for each menu
    vJsonRecord = row_to_json(vQuery                          
    );
    
    --Get the submenus of this menu
    SELECT 
      f.*
    FROM
      "FncGetMenus"(vQuery."CodMenu") f 
    INTO
      vJsonArraySubMenus;
     
    --Create an Object containing the submenus 
    SELECT 
      json_build_object('SubMenus', vJsonArraySubMenus)  
    INTO
      vJsonObjectSubMenus;
      
    raise notice 'json record: %', vJsonRecord;
    raise notice 'json object submenu: %', vJsonObjectSubMenus;
      
    --Include the SubMenus object to a new JsonObject
    vJsonMenu = vJsonRecord || vJsonObjectSubMenus;
    
    raise notice 'json vJsonMenu: %', vJsonMenu;
     
    --Append the new JsonMenu with it´s children to the result array
    
    vJsonArrayReturn = vJsonArrayReturn || vJsonMenu:: jsonb;
    
    raise notice 'result: %', vJsonArrayReturn;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN vJsonArrayReturn;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100;
```